Links to old questions are redirected to unrelated new questions
I came across an old answer on Skeptics SE that has two puzzling links to Astronomy SE:

It seems that I have finally found the answer to my question courtesy of another SE site: Is there a way to create an artificial solar eclipse?
[…]
What's more interesting, is that in the Simpsons Montgomery Burns has a device to create solar eclipses. This could be really the source of this legend, especially since the idea of the eclipse is absolutely in unison with what is (still) going on there in North Korea.

Strangely enough, these two links go to two completely different questions/answers than what appears to have been the original target:

Is there a way to create an artificial solar eclipse? → What would we find if we could travel 786 trillion light years in any direction
device to create solar eclipses → A clock travelling "faster than the speed of light"

I tried to find the relevant questions so that I could edit the original answer with the correct links, but I can't even find any similar questions here on Astronomy SE. What's going on? I must assume that the links were correct at the time of posting!

The answer there is from 2012, which is before the launch of the current Astronomy SE. There was an early attempt of an Astronomy SE that flopped, and I assume those were links to that site. I don't know if there are still archives of that site around anywhere. That would be a good question for Meta Stack Exchange.

After some digging I found that "its content has been merged into Physics", where I found the former question intact. Thanks!
